# Soap UI, REST API, update database

Tags: rest, mongodb, text, csv, soapui

I am going to use soapUI to test the REST API framework.

Is there a way through which i can insert/update records inside the MongoDB with data in a file type(csv, txt etc) using soapUI tool?

What i am trying to do is validate the API calls and update the database from a data file.

Comment: http://www.soapui.org/?utm_expid=56905-6&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Furl%3Fsa%3Dt%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26esrc%3Ds%26source%3Dweb%26cd%3D1%26ved%3D0CGwQFjAA%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.soapui.org%252F%26ei%3Dim0hUNDcH9LC6gHR3IGwCw%26usg%3DAFQjCNE0DhyxZHa40M-2y2xo7zFzQJHB0A%26sig2%3DaoMucKIAgBOIuFTPYZ_nZA

Comment: I'd look into using mongoexport to get some data out: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongoexport

Comment: I don't get why you need soap up to insert/update data in mongoDB (which can be done with http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongoimport)

Comment: Which REST API are you trying to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to use Groovy script, then you can do this pretty easily.

Put your jdbc driver in SoapUI's bin\ext directory.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/downloads
   (probably where you can it for mongodb)

Then you need roughly these things in your script:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
groovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver("org.postgresql.Driver")  // NOT SURE WHAT STRING FOR MONGODB

def connectString = "....."
sql = Sql.newInstance(connectString)  // TEST YOUR CONNECT STRING IN A SQL BROWSER
def misc = sql.firstRow("SELECT * from table")
```

groovy.sql.Sql is very nice!

http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html

Comment: So all i need is SoapUI professional, configure my API settings with SoapUI, then import the jdbc driver, write a script and match the identifiers with the API posts?

Comment: You don't need SoapUI pro.  You just need to get the JDBC driver loaded and make sure your connect string is good.  Then use a Groovy script to execute your SQL.  You can make assertions in the Groovy script based on the data matching or not.

Comment: Thanks Chris. that was helpful. So is this my solution if i need to just picturise it -> http://www.soapui.org/Data-Driven-Testing/storing-data/All-Pages.html

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use below groovy code in "Groovy test step" of your test case and connect to mongodb. Before that please ensure that mongodb java client jar file and gmongo are in {Installation Directory}\bin\ext folder of your soapUI installation

Gmongo: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gmongo/gmongo/1.5

Mongodb Java Client : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.2.2

```
import com.gmongo.GMongoClient
import com.gmongo.GMongo
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress

//def credentials = MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential('admin', 'students', 'admin' as char[])

//def client = new GMongoClient(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1:27017"))

context.gmongo=new GMongo()
def db=context.gmongo.getDB("test")
log.info db.fruit.find().count()

db.fruit.find().each{

    doc->log.info doc

    }
```